# "Inteligent" resize on layout?

Tags: android, layout

I'm having an issue working with layouts, I've a linear layout (could be a relative layout or a table layout) which will contain an undefined number of buttons when the activity is loaded. This means, the quantity of buttons will be determined when the activity is being created. The thing is, I'm trying to fit them all in one line (with a center gravity) without changing each buttons' width UNTIL one of them reaches the margin of the screen. In other words, I want the buttons JUST to resize when at least one of them reaches the margin of the screen. That is because, I can't determine the space they're going to use because they are not created.

My actual linear layout:

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout_1"
    android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout_2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">

</LinearLayout>
```

Piece of code that creates the buttons:

```
    protected void hacerVisiblesRespuesta(){
    ViewGroup linearLayout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
    assert linearLayout != null;
    int height = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,40, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    for(int i = 0; i < longuitudPalabra; i++){
        String boton = "btn_rsp" + Integer.toString(i+1);
        Button bt = new Button(this);
        bt.setText("");
        bt.setId(getResourceId(boton,"id",getPackageName()));
        bt.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT
                , height
                , 1.0f));
        bt.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                clickBotonRespuesta(v);
            }
        });
        bt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            bt.setBackground(getDrawable(R.drawable.bgbtnrsp));
        }else{
            //bt.setBackgroundDrawable(getDrawable(R.drawable.bgbtnrsp));
        }
        bt.setTextSize(20);
        Typeface typeFace= Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/Montserrat-Regular.ttf");
        bt.setTypeface(typeFace);
        linearLayout.addView(bt);
    }
}
```

I've tried many things, one of them was to make the buttons' width variable with weight property. The thing is if there are a small quantity of buttons, lets say 4, their width ended up enormous. Is there any way to achieve this through code? Thanks.

Comment: Try to give the buttons a `maxWidth` with `button.setMaxWidth();`

Comment: @TychoTheTaco still the same, buttons' width with less quantity goes really big

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this?

```
button.setLayoutParams (new LayoutParams(50, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
```

Comment: Yep, but they don't resize when they touch margins. So if I have a large quantity of buttons (8 for eg) some of them may be unrechable. This is mainly because I want to get the app working for small screen sizes mobiles

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of your issue? I understood what you're trying to say. I just wanna have a look at it.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/OwLa8JM.jpg (sorry for ext. link). There I'm using two codes differents with same quantity of buttons (the cases are switched sorry for that, so first in 14 but. goes with second in 4 but. and the others two goes together). In one of them, all buttons are being resized occupuying the maxium gap between them. In the other one, there isn't any resize so buttons goes beyond phone screen. What I want is, don't resize buttons until it's necesary, I mean, until one of them touches the margin. That's why I called an "intelligent" resize.

Comment: Set width of your buttons to 0dp and a layout_weight=1 to your
linear layout. Let me know if this works.

Comment: you mean 0dp width and weight 1 to buttons? Even though I've tried both, 0dp width to buttons and layout_weight 1 to layout and both properties to buttons. Neither of them works as I want, the second one is giving me the enormous width to small quantity of buttons.